# getting beacon node error after upgrading lighthouse client to v3.5.1

Tags: go-ethereum, error, lighthouse

getting beacon node below error after upgrading lighthouse client to v3.5.1 from v3.3.0.

CRIT Failed to start beacon node             reason: Failed to build beacon chain: Error loading finalized block: HotColdDBError(MissingFullBlockExecutionPayloadPruned(0xd17c76101803ceb7e83e0bca634b7822154db93fda8650dc7184cebaa07542f8, Slot(5193632)))
INFO Internal shutdown received              reason: Failed to start beacon node

Comment: I have the same issue when moved database and environment to other host. INFO Database version: 16 and Lighthouse v4.0.1-a53830f

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. This is an [answer](https://github.com/sigp/lighthouse/issues/4384#issuecomment-1581665632) from  lighthouse developer **michaelsproul**.
Just run lighthouse with *--prune-db* and *--checkpoint-sync-url* with one of necessary [node](https://eth-clients.github.io/checkpoint-sync-endpoints/)